# Show that $\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)<\infty$.

Tags: probability

Show that $\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)<\infty$.

I'm quite stuck on this question. So far my idea has been to try to rearrange these two quantities into forms that are more comparable to each other. So far I have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X=-n))\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n(\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X=-n))
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}X^2&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n^2\mathbb{P}(X=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2(\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X=-n))\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot n(\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X=-n))\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n n(\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X=-n)).
\end{align*}
From here, the two quantities are in pretty similary forms, where the first one looks like it is summing the tail, and the first one is summing the beginning (who knows a better term?). But I cannot see how to draw the if and only if from this. Maybe this is the wrong approach entirely, and I am missing some key theorem or something. Anybody know what I can do here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that your first equation has an error (which is corrected but not emphasized in one of the following answers).  It should be $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (\mathbb{P}(X={\color{red}k})+\mathbb{P}(X=-{\color{red}k}))$$

Comment: The question is well-posted and works for a general random variable $X$. The question itself does not assume that $X$ takes integral values only. Do not make that assumption or you will get zero mark.

Comment: You _can_ assume $X \in \mathbf{N},$ although not so obviously. Here is how. First, you can assume $X \geq 0$ by replacing $X$ with $|X|$ should the need arise. Further, we can assume $P(X = 0) = 0$ (this term adds nothing to either the series or the integral). Then, considering $Y = \sum_{k \in \mathbf{N}} k \mathbf{1}_{k-1 < X \leq k}$, we see $Y-1 \leq X \leq Y$ and so $(Y-1)^2 \leq X^2 \leq Y^2,$ so $X^2$ is integrable if and only if $Y^2$ is. Notice $P(Y > k) = P(X > k).$ So, you may replace $X$ with $Y.$

Comment: Thanks for that useful insight Will M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we prove the following Robin's identity:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $X:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$
be a non-negative random variable. Then, for any $p\in[1,\infty)$,
$$
\int X^{p}dP=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left([X>x]\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left([X\geq x]\right)dx.
$$

Proof: Let $A=\{(x,\omega)\in[0,\infty)\times\Omega\mid X(\omega)>x\}$.
We show that $A$ is jointly measurable, i.e., $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal{F}$.
Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
A & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\{(x,\omega)\mid X(\omega)>r>x\}\\
 & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(\{(x,\omega)\mid X(\omega)>r\}\cap\{(x,\omega)\mid r>x\}\right)\\
 & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left([0,\infty)\times X^{-1}\left((r,\infty)\right)\cap[0,r)\times\Omega\right)\\
 & \in & \mathcal{B}([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal{F}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $B=\{(x,\omega)\in[0,\infty)\times\Omega\mid X(\omega)\geq x\}$.
Note that $B^{c}=\{(x,\omega)\mid X(\omega)<x\}$ which can be proved
jointly measurable in a similar way. Therefore $B$ is jointly measurable.

By Tonelli-Fubini Theorem, we have that
$$
\int\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}1_{A}(x,\omega)\,d\lambda(x)\right)dP(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int px^{p-1}1_{A}(x,\omega)\,dP(\omega)\right)d\lambda(x),
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\infty)$. Observe
that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}1_{A}(x,\omega)\,d\lambda(x)\right)dP(\omega) & = & \int\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{[0,X(\omega))}(x)px^{p-1}dx\right)dP(\omega)\\
 & = & \int X^{p}dP.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int px^{p-1}1_{A}(x,\omega)\,dP(\omega)\right)d\lambda(x) & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left([X>x]\right)dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $\int X^{p}dP=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left([X>x]\right)dx$.
By replacing $A$ with $B$ and applying Tonelli-Fubini Theorem again,
we have
$$
\int X^{p}dP=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left([X\geq x]\right)dx.
$$

---

We go back to your question. By replacing $X$ with $|X|$, without
loss of generality, we may assume that $X\geq0$. Suppose that $\int X^{2}dP<\infty$.
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xP\left([X>x]\right)dx & = & \frac{1}{2}\int X^{2}dP<\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
By Monotone Convergence Theorem, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xP\left([X>x]\right)dx & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1_{[k,k+1)}(x)\cdot xP\left([X>x]\right)dx\\
 & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}xP\left([X>x]\right)dx\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}kP\left([X>k+1]\right)dx\\
 & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left([X>k+1]\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left([X>k+1]\right)<\infty$. Observe
that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)P\left([X>k+1]\right) & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left([X>k+1]\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left([X>k+1]\right)\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left([X>k+1]\right)+ 1 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left([X>k+1]\right) \\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\int X^{2}dP<\infty\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP\left([X>n]\right)<\infty$.

Conversely, suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP\left([X>n]\right)<\infty$.
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xP\left([X>x]\right)dx & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}xP\left([X>x]\right)dx\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}(k+1)P\left([X>k]\right)dx\\
 & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)P\left([X>k]\right)\\
 & \leq & 1+ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2k\cdot P\left([X>k]\right)\\
 & = & 1+ 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\cdot P\left([X>k]\right)\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP\left([X>n]\right)<\infty\Rightarrow\int X^{2}dP<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $X$ is positive, then $$\sum_{n \in \mathbf{N}} n P(X > n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \sum_{k > n} nP(X = k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbf{N}} \sum_{n < k} n P(X = k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbf{N}} \dfrac{k(k-1)}{2} P(X = k)$$

Comment: You may need to use the fact that if $(a_{n,k})$ is a doubly-indexed series of positive numbers, then $\sum_n \sum_k a_{n,k} = \sum_k \sum_n a_{n,k}$ __always.__

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}X^2&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty k^2\mathbb{P}(X=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2(\mathbb{P}(X=k)+\mathbb{P}(X=-k)).
\end{align*}
We also have that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n(\mathbb{P}(X=k)+\mathbb{P}(X=-k))\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty(\mathbb{P}(X=k)+\mathbb{P}(X=-k))\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)}2(\mathbb{P}(X=k)+\mathbb{P}(X=-k)).\\
\end{align*}
And now the if and only if is obvious.

Comment: You could have also used that $|x|^2 = x^2$ and not have to split between signs (i.e. you replace $X$ with $|X|$ and assume that $X$ is non negative.

Comment: The first line must be wrong because if the random variable $X$ does not take integral values, then RHS is zero. For example, consider the constant random variable $X= 1/2$, OP never says that $X$ takes integral values only.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan it's implied in OP

Comment: @Snoop OP never implies that $X$ takes integral values only. Actually, this question is well-posted and is true for a general random variable $X$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I wonder why the attempt in the OP uses only integers then

Comment: @Snoop It is a mistake.