# Covering a probability space with a sequence of sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

**Let $E_n$ be a sequence of events with $\inf_n {\bf P}(E_n) = \delta > 0$. I need to demonstrate that the lower bound $$\mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n \leq N} 1_{E_n} \geq \delta \frac{N}{2} \right) \geq \delta/2$$ holds for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$.**

I have tried several tricks. Intuitively/geometrically, I understand this assertion fully. For instance, if $E_n$ are disjoint, then at least $[1/\delta]$ sets of them ought to intersect somewhere; hence the inequality. I have tried to attack the problem from several angles, for instance

- for the integer $K=[\delta N/2]$
  \begin{align}
  \mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{E_n} \geq \delta \frac{N}{2} \right)
  &= \mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{E_n} \geq K \right) = \sum_{k=K}^{N}\mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{E_n} = k \right)\\
  &= \sum_{k=K}^{N} \sum_{p \in \{P\subseteq\{1,\ldots,N\}\mid|P|=k\}}\mathop{\bf P}\left( \bigcap_{i\in p} \{1_{E_i} = k\} \right)
  \end{align}
- I also have tried induction, i.e., under the induction hypothesis
  $$\mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} 1_{E_n} \geq \delta \frac{N+1}{2} \right) =\\ \mathop{\bf P}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{E_n} \geq \delta \frac{N+1}{2} \right) 
  + \mathop{\bf P}\left( \{\sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{E_n} < \delta \frac{N}{2} \} \text{ and } \{1_{E_{N+1}}=1\} \right)$$

I have tried approaching the problem from several other angles but nothing brings me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of “Reverse Markov Inequality”.

Let $$X_N:=\frac1N\sum_{n\le N}\mathbf1_{E_n}.$$
Then $\mathbf E\,X_N=\delta$ and, because $X_N\le1$,
$$\mathbf P\!\left(X_N\le\frac\delta2\right)=\mathbf P\!\left(1-X_N\ge1-\frac\delta2\right)\le\frac{\mathbf E[1-X_N]}{1-\frac\delta2}=\frac{1-\delta}{1-\frac\delta2}=1-\frac{\delta}{2-\delta},$$
where we applied the classical Markov inequality. Hence
$$\mathbf P\!\left(X_N>\frac\delta2\right)=1-\mathbf P\!\left(X_N\le\frac\delta2\right)\ge\frac\delta{2-\delta}\ge\frac\delta2.$$

Comment: This a very cool technique moving inequalities around like this to be able to apply Markov in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$
such that the proposition is false. Define $X=\sum_{n=1}^{N}1_{E_{n}}$,
then $P(X\geq\frac{N\delta}{2})<\frac{\delta}{2}$.

Since $X$ is non-negative, for any $p\geq1$, we have that
$$
E\left[X^{p}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P(X\geq x)dx.
$$
The above is known as Robin identity and can be proved by Fubini Theorem.
Note that $P(X\geq x)=0$ for any $x>N$ and $P(X\geq x)\leq P(X\geq\frac{N\delta}{2})<\frac{\delta}{2}$
for any $x\in[\frac{N\delta}{2},N]$, so we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[X] & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X\geq x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{N}P(X\geq x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\frac{N\delta}{2}}P(X\geq x)dx+\int_{\frac{N\delta}{2}}^{N}P(X\geq x)dx\\
 & \leq & \frac{N\delta}{2}\cdot1+\frac{\delta}{2}(N-\frac{N\delta}{2})\\
 & = & N\delta-\frac{N\delta^{2}}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, $E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}P(E_{n})\geq N\delta$. Hence,
we obtain $N\delta\leq E[X]\leq N\delta-\frac{N\delta^{2}}{4}$, which
is a contradiction.

Comment: I proved the Robin identity in my old post. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212204/show-that-mathbbex2-infty-if-and-only-if-sum-n-1-infty-n-cdot-mathbb/4212516#4212516