# $L^p$-norm through the distribution function.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The question is about the using of Fubini's theorem in the following proof.

[image]

**Question 1 :** Fubini's theorem for me looks like $$\int_Y \int_X f(x,y)dxdy=\int_X \int_Y f(x,y)dydx.$$ But I can not understand how they use it in the proof. Can you make this more clear for me?  I dont understand how they get $\int_0^{|f(x)|}$

**My attampt:**
STEP 1: We will use the next fact: If we have a function $f$ on the $E$ and $A\subset E$ then we have $$\int_E \chi_A f dx=\int_A f dx.(*)$$

Then $$p\int_0^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}d_f(\alpha)d\alpha = p\int_0^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\int_X\chi_{\{x:|f(x)|>\alpha\}}d\mu d\alpha= 
\int_0^{\infty}\int_X p\alpha^{p-1}\chi_{\{x:|f(x)|>\alpha\}}d\mu d\alpha.$$

STEP 2: Then we say that it is hard (or imposible?) to integrate $\int_X\chi_{x:|f(x)|>\alpha}d\mu$ and change the order of integration $$\int_X\int_0^{\infty}p\alpha^{p-1}\chi_{\{x:|f(x)|>\alpha\}}d\alpha d\mu.$$ Then we use (*) in the inner integral and get $$\int_X\int_0^{|f(x)|}p\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha d\mu.$$ And so on.

**Question 2:** Is my steps correct?

Comment: The steps look correct. In my opinion, it is more natural to start with $\int_{X}|f|^p \,d\mu$ and the arrive at the final formula so that the final formula doesn't seem like magic.

Comment: @Mason Can you give some reference how to get  this formula as you say?

Comment: I don't have a reference. That is just the way that I would solve this if I were asked to prove it. It is just doing your proof but in reverse "following your nose".

Comment: The textbook does not show explicitly the integrand nor the joint-measurability of the integrand (joint-measurability, i.e., measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebras must be checked before applying Fubini theorem). You may get some idea from my old post, which clearly indicates the integrand and proves the joint-measurability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote and proved something similar in my old post.
You may be able to get some idea from it.
In probability theory, that proposition is known as Robin's theorem.

[Show that $\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)<\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212204/show-that-mathbbex2-infty-if-and-only-if-sum-n-1-infty-n-cdot-mathbb/4212516#4212516)